# Issue when differentiating metadata for UILabel?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, substring

I am fetching meta data for the radio streams that currently being played in my iOS app, (Artist Name, track name). However this meta data comes in one piece i.e = "FRANK SINATRA - THEME FROM NEW YORK, NEW YORK".

While this is okay, It would look much nice if I had 2 different labels styled differently one saying "FRANK SINATRA" while the other would read "THEME FROM NEW YORK, NEW YORK".

To do this, I have to get rid of the hyphen,

```
    _metaData = infoString;   // THIS IS THE OLD 1- LABEL FOR  DATA ALL WAY

    // THIS IS THE CODE I AM IMPLEMENTING TO GET RID OF THE HYPHEN

    NSUInteger xxx = [_metaData rangeOfString:@"-"].location;


    NSUInteger xxxPlustTwo = xxx + 2;

    NSString *xxxx = [_metaData substringToIndex:xxx];

    self.artistName.text=xxxx;

    NSString *trackInformation = [_trackName substringFromIndex:xxxPlustTwo];

    self.soundInfoMeta.text = trackInformation;
```

And just like that I am able to break the 2 apart, problem is that when the station goes to commercial my app immediately crashes. The following is the error I receive on Xcode:
`***Terminating app due to uncaught exception ‘NSRangeException’, reason: ‘***-[__NSCFString substringToIndex:]: Index 2147483647 out of bounds; string length 17’`

What can be causing this problem?

Update: I tried changing the `NSUInteger` to `double` but this did not fix the problem, here is the latest crash log:

```
xxxx    NSString *  nil 0x00000000
NSObject    NSObject        
isa Class   0x0 
xxx double  2147483647  2147483647
xplus   double  2147483649  2147483649
_trackName  __NSCFString *  @"http://www.181.fm"    0x16d8a890
NSObject    NSObject        
isa Class   __NSCFString    0x39d9a8f8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably getting input that has no hyphen, so the `location` of the the hyphen is `NSNotFound` which is defined to be `NSIntegerMax`, I believe. Your code needs to be robust to this.

This is a bit different from how you're doing it now, but it should work on more types of input:

```
NSString *infoString = @"ARTIST - TRACK";
NSArray *infoStringComponents = [infoString componentsSeparatedByString:@" - "];
__block NSString *artistString = @"";
__block NSString *trackInfoString = @"";

if ([infoStringComponents count] == 0) {
    // This case should only happen when there's no info string at all
    artistString = @"Unknown Artist";
    trackInfoString = @"Unknown Song";
}
else if ([infoStringComponents count] == 1) {
    // If no hyphens just display the whole string as the track info
    trackInfoString = infoStringComponents[0];
}
else {
    [infoStringComponents enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *component, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
        NSString *trimmedComponent = [component stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
        if (index == 0) {
            artistString = trimmedComponent;
        }
        else {
            NSString *buffer = @"";
            if ([trackInfoString length] > 0) {
                buffer = @" - ";
            }
            trackInfoString = [trackInfoString stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@%@",buffer,trimmedComponent];
        }
    }];
}
```

You could also check if the `location` property of the range you derive is equal to `NSNotFound` and then just assume you can't derive an artist out of it and display your `_metaData` variable in an appropriate label. For example:

```
NSRange hyphenRange = [infoString rangeOfString:@"-"];
if (hyphenRange.location == NSNotFound) {
    // Display only infoString to the user, unformatted into artist / song info
}
else {
    // Try the same technique you're attempting now
}
```

Comment: What a great answer, it's been the best one i have gotten here at SO. If I could give you all my rep I totally would. Thanks for taking the time! Really appreciate it